# Overlay object properties with temporary ones?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm having trouble figuring out how to structure this.

I have a class `VehicleState` with properties including `passengers`:

```
public class VehicleState
{
    public int _temp_passengers;
    public int _passengers;
    public int passengers
    {
        set { _temp_passengers = value; }
        get { return _passengers; }
    }
    public void CommitState()
    {
        _passengers = _temp_passengers;
    }
}
```

There is a loop that fires every X seconds. Each vehicle affects another within the simulation.

In order to avoid corrupting the properties as each vehicle affects others, I'm storing them within a temp field, e.g. `_passengers`. The temp value is committed to the regular value at the end of the loop.

---

The problem is the following:

```
passengers = passengers - 1;
passengers += 1
```

which becomes:

```
_temp_passengers = _passengers - 1;
```

**EDIT:**

To explain the problem further, imagine 10 Vehicles affect Vehicle A, increasing passengers by 1. Each passenger leaves their vehicle to get on board of Vehicle A.

So the operation `passengers += 1` would be called 10 times, but it will be as if the operation was just called once!

---

- Is there a design pattern to solve this?
- Can I wrap each property like this in a Class?
- Can I add the `+=` and `-=` conditions within `set{}`?

Any ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: You've got a bigger problem at the moment - if you *fetch* your `passengers` property, it will blow up as it recurses forever...

Comment: But fundamentally, you've only got a single field - surely you need *two* fields, one for the "temporary" value, and one for the "committed" value.

Comment: Is this an average household car, carrying 2.34 passengers (or: why do you use `float`)?

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh my! Let me fix that... Mondays :)

Comment: @CodeCaster It was just for commodity, but the context of the question doesn't make sense. Changed it to `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a kind of deferred execution

```
public class VehicleState
{
    List<Action> actionList = new List<Action>();

    public int passengers { get; set; }

    public void CommitState()
    {
        foreach (var action in actionList)
        {
            action();
        }
    }

    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        actionList.Add(action);
    }
}
```

Test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        var vs = new VehicleState { passengers = 3 };
        vs.Execute(() => vs.passengers += 1);
        Assert.AreEqual(3, vs.passengers);
        vs.CommitState();
        Assert.AreEqual(4, vs.passengers);

    }
```

## Limits of this solution

This solutions just provides a deferred execution. Depending on your scenario, this might be usefull or not.

```
var vs1 = new VehicleState { passengers = 3 };
var vs2 = new VehicleState { passengers = 3 };

vs1.Execute(() => vs1.passengers += vs2.passengers);
// vs2.Execute(() => vs2.passengers -= vs1.passengers); // does not work

// remember state before 
var beforeVs1passengers = vs1.passengers;
vs2.Execute(() => vs2.passengers -= beforeVs1passengers);  // that works

vs1.CommitState();  // order might be important, no common state, no stack
vs2.CommitState();
Assert.AreEqual(6, vs1.passengers);
Assert.AreEqual(0, vs2.passengers);
```

Comment: Sure;) Please be aware of the possible trap of lazy evaluation. I found a good example at [this blog](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/closures-in-c-can-be-evil/)

Comment: Thanks for the edit! So the variables are just references, and the "non working" example would probably cause `vs2.passenger == -3`? I didn't know about Delegates and Events in C# before... this has been quite interesting. :)

Comment: I think I may go without Actions and avoid any "smart" ways, and just explicitly use the temp/non-temp variables accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

let's try

```
public class VehicleState
{
    public float _passengers;
    public float _CommitedPassengers;
    public float passengers
    {
        set { _passengers = value; }
        get { return _passengers; }
    }

    public float CommitedPassengers
    {
        get { return _CommitedPassengers; }
    }

    public void CommitState()
    {
        _CommitedPassengers = _passengers;

    }
}
```

i think that's all you need

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Fixed my question, any chance you could give it an extra look? :)

Comment: The problem is doing `passengers += 1` without having to do `passengers = _temp_passengers + 1`

Comment: @RadiantHex if i understand you correctly you just want to do passengers++ in the setter? you can, bet it's better to ceate a method for that

Answer (score 0):

As a late comment on a rather old question - I don't think that "overlayed properties" are a good fit here. You are trying to mix in two different states of the model into one instance. You already reported some of the issues that this brings along. Also, the code will be hardish to understand and maintain.

Instead, use two versions of your model `M`, representing the states of the two iterations `n` and `n+1`. Your calculations take `M[n]` as their input and produce/modify `M[n+1]` as their output.

You then need a way to copy the new state from your `nextModel` into `currentModel`:

```
var currentModel = new Model();

for (var n in Enumerable.Range(0, 99))
{
    var nextModel = calculate(currentModel);

    currentModel.UpdateFrom(nextModel);
}
```

Whereas by `Model` I refer to the entirety of all vehicles and whatever else is part of your simulation, and by `calculate` I refer to the entirety of all calculations done in one iteration.

This is close to what you were doing, it just collects your "keep two states and copy later" logic which was spread across all properties into a single place called `UpdateFrom`. Having two instances of the model gives you a way to be very clear about what state of the model a calculation is based upon:

```
nextModel.Vehicles[0].passengers =
    nextModel.Vehicles[0].passengers + currentModel.Vehicles[1].passengers
```

Once you have multiple instances you could also choose to move more towards a functional programming style, produce a new model in each iteration and throwing away the old states (or keeping it for a record if you need it):

```
var model = new Model[100];
model[0] = new Model();

for (var n in Enumerable.Range(0, 99))
{
    // either throw away old state and keep a reference to the new state only
    var currentModel = calculate(currentModel);

    // or keep all states
    model[n+1] = calculate(model[n]);
}
```